# QGIS plugin 'sextante' not loading after upgrading to Mac OS X 10.8

Tags: qgis, mac

Any known issue with sexante and Mac OS X 10.8? After updating from 10.7 and even after reinstalling GDAL sexante is still not working...

Comment: Are you getting any Errors? Saying that it 'is not working' won't help us much in solving the issue.

Comment: Couldn't load plugin 'sextante' from ['/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python', '/Users/myname/.qgis//python', ...

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: The answer I think is psycopg2. The package needs to be reinstalled after upgrading to Mountain Lion. Not 100% sure though, but now I don't receive error message any more.